# Application does not exit when an error happening on systemd

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, systemd

So I developed an application using `.net-core`, I run this software on a linux machine as a `daemon` service using `systemd`. Now the problem is that when an error happen in the app, it enters in a "limbo", infact each activity of the application is logged using `Console.WriteLine` and I can see this log typing that command on linux machine: `journalctl -fu app.service`.

When the error happen the log doesn't write anything, but at the same time the application keep running and this is really strange because I setup the service with the following configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description = Daemon service

[Service]
ExecStart = /usr/bin/dotnet /home/my username/Desktop/publish/SimpleApp.dll
WorkingDirectory= /home/foo/Desktop/publish
Restart = always
RestartSec = 3

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

as you can see the `Restart = always` should restart the app when an error is raised. When an exception is raised the method `Error()` write the error inside a file and then kill the software in the following way:

```
public void Error(Exception ex)
{
   File.WriteAllText("error.txt", ex.ToString());
   Environment.Exit(1); 
}
```

Must be some problem on `Environment.Exit` with the `Linux` environment, or I did something wrong calling `Environment.Exit`. There are other ways to close an application like this which run as system service?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to me you capture the exception but do not thros a new error. This mean the system does not know an error occured

Comment: @Aldert do you propose a solution?

Comment: A couple of things: (a) are you sure `Error()` is really called?` Does the `error.txt` file exist? (b) from a daemon don't assume relative paths, use `/tmp/error.txt` or `/var/error.txt` or alike. (c) I wouldn't assume `Environment.Exit()` does not work. Rather that your application is restarted immediately by `systemd` (hence `Restart = always` in your config).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public void Error(Exception ex)
{
   File.WriteAllText("error.txt", ex.ToString());
   throw new Exception ("This is a test to see if restart is working");
}
```